# Defining Importance of variables in regression and variable selection

Tags: regression, logistic, feature-selection, lasso, importance

When doing variable selection, one of the most asked questions is which variables are most important, or rank the variables in order of importance. Typically in linear or logistic regression, the importance of one predictor tends to depend on the coefficients of other predictors in the model, e.g. LASSO paths cross, Wald's chi-squared change as predictors are removed.

However, while performing LASSO in regression, is it statistically correct that, if we define importance as the variables that relatively have the best predictive capability, then the importance of variable can be deduced from the graph showing which factors are sequentially deleted from the model as the penalty increase.

For instance, can we say that based on the definition of importance made above, the increasing order of importance from the figure below is 4-2-1-3
[image]

Also, if this is not true, how can we define the importance of variables in and L1 penalized logistic regression, ie. How can we somehow relate the coefficient to a higher probability of belonging to a specific group?